# How to fix a Circular Dependency Error in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a cell (games played) that adds 3 variables (wins, loses, and draws), and doesn't display anything when they have no value.

```
=IF(D5+D6+D7 = 0, "", D5+D6+D7)
```

My variable wins (and the others when I add code them) detect when the word Wins appears in the same column as it. It also doesn't display anything when it has no value.

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(D10:D29, "*Win*")) > 0, SUM(COUNTIF(D10:D29, "*Win*")), IF(D8 > 0, 0, ""))
```

I want it to display a 0 *only* when games played is more than 0 (so I don't have a bunch of zeros on the sheet) After making it display a 0 when games played is more than 0, it started giving me Circular Dependency Error. How can I fix this?

Here's a link to my file: [Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U616HsdKBg0hI8XP09jBtwVffUsklUUuU6yiwKpr1e0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**cell D5:**

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(D10:D49, "*Win*"))>0, SUM(COUNTIF(D10:D49, "*Win*")),
 IF(D8<>"", 0,))
```

**cell D11:**

```
=IF(D10>D2,"Win: "&D10&" +"&D10-D2&" SR",
 IF(AND(D10=D2,D2>0),"Draw: "&D10&" "&"+0 SR",
 IF(AND(D10<D2,D10>0),"Lose: "&D10&" "&D10-D2&" SR","")))
```

**Circular Dependency Error** was generated, because cell **D11** was returning **FALSE**

[image]

Comment: This didn't change anything, sorry

Comment: @Erose524 change cell D5 to get rid of those zeros. see gif